# Fundamentals of XL algorithm

Tags: cryptanalysis, multivariate-cryptography

I am trying to understand XL algorithm and F4/F5 algorithms for solving multivariate polynomial systems.
Is XL related to the Grobner basis?
I would be grateful if anyone could suggest me the topics (related to solving degree, groebner basis?) I need to read to understand these algorithms.
Thanks!

Comment: See the [Bards Book](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75364/18298) in action

Comment: @kelalaka, Thanks you so much for providing this reference!